# Search View: Setting the hint Icon to the right outside of a toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview

I have the search view default search icon set to the right by using

```
 android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

However in my usecase I have to have the search query hint showing by default which I do by using

```
     app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
```

However in the query hint the search icon jumps back to the left. Would anyone know how to set the query hint search icon to the right. Thsi search view is NOT inside an app tool bar.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if the text you're providing via `android:queryHint` is in an RTL language, it will work fine. For example, in Hebrew:

```
<SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:queryHint="רמז"/>
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any trick to make it work with a LTR language.

Answer (score 0):

Add `textDirection`

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:queryHint="ABC"/>
```

Or just create `EditText`

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:hint="ABC"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:drawableEnd="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in your SearchView, it would work like a charm.

```
app:searchHintIcon="@null"
```